# Get request with CURL along with SSL

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to access a rest end point from CURL .

I have below files and information.

```
cacerts == /usr/bin/cacert_file
key_alias== alias-name
key_password==pwd
```

I am using the below curl command to call

```
curl --cacert /usr/bin/cacert_file  "https//server.com/data"
```

**I keep connection timeout error.How can i solve the issue?**
Below code is from other team who is exposing the rest end point. Rest End point has SSL enabled.when i checked the code it says

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/data", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getData() {
        
        return "Hello World";
    }

server:
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    client-auth: need
    key-store: {keystore-path}
    key-store-password: {keystore-password}
    key-alias: alias-name
    key-store-type: JKS
```

Comment: `https//host.server.com/data` - did you mean to write `https://...` instead of `https//...` or is this an actual error in how you call the server?

Comment: actual error .what you pointed is a typo

Comment: do i need to import any certificates ...i am not well aware of SSL

Comment: Please edit your question to fix this typo then. Also *"connection timeout"* likely means that the server is not reachable by the client, i.e. wrong hostname, wrong DNS setup, wrong setup on the server, firewall in between or similar. This is not related to SSL.

Comment: ok but when i disable the SSL in server site..i am able to call the server and get the response

Comment: Test the connection at a slightly lower level using netcat (`nc -v server.com 443`), the openssl client `openssl s_client -connect server.com:443` which gives you a TLS handshake from the client to the server. This would allow you to determine if you are able to connect to the client at the TCP level, and then at the TLS level.

Comment: *"...when i disable the SSL in server site..i am able to call the server and get the response..."* - plain HTTP and HTTPS use different ports and setups. For example if the firewall is blocking port 443 but allowing port 80 then plain HTTP will work but HTTPS not-.